# PHP server event handling

Tags: php, events, event-handling

I am looking for a way to have like a button in a web page, only when you press it the event handling is a program in a server. Like a trigger to execute a program in the server.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "program in the server" exactly. How does this differ from calling a PHP page?

Comment: I meant like a program, in java or python, running in the server, that handles the event in the web pages.

Answer (score 0):

A PHP script can execute a command on the server using one of the various functions like `exec`, `system`, and `passthru`. It can be a security nightmare, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into something like: http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

AJAX for the client part (sending notification about the button being pressed), and PHP (function exec() ou  system()  ).

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have said, exec, system, and passthru can be used for that, but I believe you will need to disable safe mode.

safe_mode = Off

http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php

To add on to this answer, you can make a form

Page1.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="script.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

script.php

```
<?php
shell_exec("cmd");
echo "done";
?>
```

Someone correct me if I am wrong here.